# How Do I Get A Similar Domain Name To Redirect To My Website?

Tags: html, redirect, dns

I have been trying to create a domain where, when you visit it, you will be redirected to a certain website in **my** domain. There are many examples of this that I can show, for one:

**TYPED INTO ADDRESS BAR**

```
alienware.com
```

**REDIRECTED TO**

```
https://www.dell.com/en-us/gaming/alienware
```

How is this possible? Must I buy the second domain? Is this done through `.htaccess`? Thank you in advance, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to buy the second domain.

Most domain registrars nowadays offer the redirection as first-class feature (NameCheap for example). Then you don't have to do anything special and can configure the redirect target directly in the DNS control panel.

Otherwise, you would have to point the domain's DNS records to a webserver and serve a redirect. This can be done in the webserver configuration directly, or in case of Apache you can also point the associated web root to an otherwise-unused directory and use a `.htaccess` file with a `Redirect` directive inside, as you mentioned.